# PyTorch training attribute doesn't exists in C++ module

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, libtorch

I have a script that was traced and saved using `torch.jit.save`, when I load it in python using:

```
  net = torch.jit.load(r"script.pt")
  net.to('cuda')
  net.train()
  print(net.training)
  net.eval()
  print(net.training)
```

I get the expected output:

```
True
False
```

However, when I load the same file using libtorch with this code:

```
  auto module = torch::jit::load("script.pt");
  module.to(torch::kCUDA);
  module.train();
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << module.is_training() << std::endl;
  module.eval();
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << module.is_training() << std::endl;
```

the output is

```
true
true
```

stepping into the `is_training()` function, it looks for the `training` attribute but it doesn't exists so it defaults to true

```
  /// True if the module is in training mode.
  bool is_training() const {
    return attr("training", true).toBool();
  }
```

Using this module works, I can call its `forward` and process data, but I need to be able to set the training mode to `false`

Any thoughts? Is there something that needs to be done when tracing?

I'm using PyTorch 1.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with CUDA 10.2

Comment: Guess you should do `model.eval()` before tracing. You can also check that the model behaves like in training mode. If you have dropouts, you'll get different results for same inputs every time.

Comment: Why would that help? and also, why does it work in pytorch but not in the c++ libtorch?

Comment: Because `model.eval()` sets training to `False`. When you perform tracing, PyTorch makes a forward pass with sample inputs and records computational graph. If `model.training == False`, then dropouts are inactive in Python, and don't get into a traced model.
I think distinguishing between training and eval state is just not implemented in C++ backend.

Comment: @Lablabla as roman said, you must run the tracing on the `eval()`ed model! and this is also stated in the documentation.